# Fill dataframe column based on result of a function applied to another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to create a new column in Pandas dataframe and put either "yellow" or "pink" as values, based on custom function output. I want to put "gray" in every remaining cell.

Currently I am using the below:

```
def assign_color(seff):
        seff = ast.literal_eval(seff)    
        for seg in seff:
            if seg['kom_rank'] is not None:
                if seg['kom_rank'] == 1:
                    return "yellow"
                if seg['kom_rank'] > 1: 
                    return "pink"

df['color'] = np.nan
df['color'] = df['segment_efforts'].map(assign_color)
df['color'].fillna(value='grey', inplace=True)
print(df['color'])
```

, which does the job, but is long and not very elegant.

I would prefer to use `np.where` as below:

```
def check_rank(seff):
        seff = ast.literal_eval(seff)    
        for seg in seff:
            if seg['kom_rank'] is not None:
                if seg['kom_rank'] == 1:
                    return "Best"
                if seg['kom_rank'] > 1: 
                    return "Top 10"

df['color'] = np.where(df['segment_efforts'].map(check_rank) == 'Best', 'yellow', 'grey')
```

But I don't know where to proceed from here to fill "pink" whenever the result of `check_rank` is "Top 10".

If I just add another similar line:

```
df['color'] = np.where(df['segment_efforts'].map(check_rank) == 'Top 10', 'pink', 'grey')
```

, it will overwrite yellows generated by the previous one.

Example `seff`:

```
[{'id': 48661869801, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Wał między kanałami (w stronę jazu)', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 197, 'moving_time': 197, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T07:52:32Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T09:52:32Z', 'distance': 1431.3, 'start_index': 51, 'end_index': 81, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 91.1, 'average_heartrate': 120.7, 'max_heartrate': 127.0, 'segment': {'id': 11627339, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Wał między kanałami (w stronę jazu)', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 1478.3, 'average_grade': -0.1, 'maximum_grade': 4.5, 'elevation_high': 165.4, 'elevation_low': 161.0, 'start_latlng': [51.11397, 17.110259], 'end_latlng': [51.104064, 17.124343], 'start_latitude': 51.11397, 'start_longitude': 17.110259, 'end_latitude': 51.104064, 'end_longitude': 17.124343, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Województwo dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661869887, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Swojszyce (wał powodziowy) ->->-> Polanowice', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 1213, 'moving_time': 1213, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:01:12Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:01:12Z', 'distance': 8601.1, 'start_index': 146, 'end_index': 326, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 91.4, 'average_heartrate': 127.2, 'max_heartrate': 137.0, 'segment': {'id': 18074584, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Swojszyce (wał powodziowy) ->->-> Polanowice', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 8597.3, 'average_grade': -0.0, 'maximum_grade': 5.4, 'elevation_high': 119.3, 'elevation_low': 110.8, 'start_latlng': [51.114345, 17.132388], 'end_latlng': [51.162349, 17.052064], 'start_latitude': 51.114345, 'start_longitude': 17.132388, 'end_latitude': 51.162349, 'end_longitude': 17.052064, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Województwo dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661870023, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Rowerowy Szlak Odry - północ (na zachód)', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 2322, 'moving_time': 2322, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:01:31Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:01:31Z', 'distance': 16159.6, 'start_index': 149, 'end_index': 509, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 86.1, 'average_heartrate': 125.9, 'max_heartrate': 143.0, 'segment': {'id': 18899204, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Rowerowy Szlak Odry - północ (na zachód)', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 16220.6, 'average_grade': -0.0, 'maximum_grade': 17.9, 'elevation_high': 119.3, 'elevation_low': 109.9, 'start_latlng': [51.115788, 17.131927], 'end_latlng': [51.201551, 16.972911], 'start_latitude': 51.115788, 'start_longitude': 17.131927, 'end_latitude': 51.201551, 'end_longitude': 16.972911, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Województwo dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661869833, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Grobla Widawska/ul.Kowalska', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 588, 'moving_time': 588, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:01:31Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:01:31Z', 'distance': 4210.5, 'start_index': 149, 'end_index': 230, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 94.1, 'average_heartrate': 128.2, 'max_heartrate': 136.0, 'segment': {'id': 14722285, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Grobla Widawska/ul.Kowalska', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 4204.0, 'average_grade': -0.1, 'maximum_grade': 12.4, 'elevation_high': 120.1, 'elevation_low': 111.3, 'start_latlng': [51.115755, 17.132015], 'end_latlng': [51.142112, 17.097938], 'start_latitude': 51.115755, 'start_longitude': 17.132015, 'end_latitude': 51.142112, 'end_longitude': 17.097938, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': None, 'state': None, 'country': None, 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661869862, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa grobla Krzywoustego - Sołtysowicka', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 310, 'moving_time': 310, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:11:26Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:11:26Z', 'distance': 2161.4, 'start_index': 233, 'end_index': 290, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 85.5, 'average_heartrate': 124.5, 'max_heartrate': 134.0, 'segment': {'id': 15782098, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa grobla Krzywoustego - Sołtysowicka', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 2163.0, 'average_grade': 0.2, 'maximum_grade': 16.7, 'elevation_high': 122.6, 'elevation_low': 112.1, 'start_latlng': [51.142559, 17.097939], 'end_latlng': [51.155109, 17.077992], 'start_latitude': 51.142559, 'start_longitude': 17.097939, 'end_latitude': 51.155109, 'end_longitude': 17.077992, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Województwo dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661869908, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa grobla Sołtysowicka-Kamieńskiego', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 335, 'moving_time': 335, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:16:46Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:16:46Z', 'distance': 2404.1, 'start_index': 292, 'end_index': 335, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 94.7, 'average_heartrate': 129.2, 'max_heartrate': 139.0, 'segment': {'id': 16476828, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa grobla Sołtysowicka-Kamieńskiego', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 2398.5, 'average_grade': -0.2, 'maximum_grade': 11.9, 'elevation_high': 122.6, 'elevation_low': 108.1, 'start_latlng': [51.155393, 17.076897], 'end_latlng': [51.165496, 17.048086], 'start_latitude': 51.155393, 'start_longitude': 17.076897, 'end_latitude': 51.165496, 'end_longitude': 17.048086, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': None, 'state': None, 'country': None, 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661869942, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa Grobla Kamienskiego-Zmigrodzka', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 347, 'moving_time': 347, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:22:40Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:22:40Z', 'distance': 2432.5, 'start_index': 341, 'end_index': 390, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 83.6, 'average_heartrate': 125.3, 'max_heartrate': 134.0, 'segment': {'id': 16635550, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa Grobla Kamienskiego-Zmigrodzka', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 2418.8, 'average_grade': 0.1, 'maximum_grade': 5.4, 'elevation_high': 257.6, 'elevation_low': 253.0, 'start_latlng': [51.165871, 17.046801], 'end_latlng': [51.178321, 17.024561], 'start_latitude': 51.165871, 'start_longitude': 17.046801, 'end_latitude': 51.178321, 'end_longitude': 17.024561, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': None, 'state': None, 'country': None, 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661869965, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa Grobla Kamienskiego-Zmigrodzka', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 347, 'moving_time': 347, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:22:40Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:22:40Z', 'distance': 2432.5, 'start_index': 341, 'end_index': 390, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 83.6, 'average_heartrate': 125.3, 'max_heartrate': 134.0, 'segment': {'id': 16635551, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa Grobla Kamienskiego-Zmigrodzka', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 2418.8, 'average_grade': 0.1, 'maximum_grade': 5.4, 'elevation_high': 257.6, 'elevation_low': 253.0, 'start_latlng': [51.165871, 17.046801], 'end_latlng': [51.178321, 17.024561], 'start_latitude': 51.165871, 'start_longitude': 17.046801, 'end_latitude': 51.178321, 'end_longitude': 17.024561, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Lower Silesian Voivodeship', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': True}, {'id': 48661869994, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa Grobla Zmigrodzka-Pegowska', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 568, 'moving_time': 568, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:30:19Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:30:19Z', 'distance': 3827.8, 'start_index': 411, 'end_index': 500, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 76.7, 'average_heartrate': 124.0, 'max_heartrate': 143.0, 'segment': {'id': 16635554, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Nowa Grobla Zmigrodzka-Pegowska', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 3850.0, 'average_grade': 0.1, 'maximum_grade': 9.2, 'elevation_high': 260.2, 'elevation_low': 257.4, 'start_latlng': [51.180654, 17.015249], 'end_latlng': [51.200937, 16.974916], 'start_latitude': 51.180654, 'start_longitude': 17.015249, 'end_latitude': 51.200937, 'end_longitude': 16.974916, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Województwo dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661870047, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Ninja vs Wild Pigs TT1 1.9km', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 270, 'moving_time': 270, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:48:05Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:48:05Z', 'distance': 1822.4, 'start_index': 587, 'end_index': 629, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 77.5, 'average_heartrate': 120.7, 'max_heartrate': 127.0, 'segment': {'id': 14915488, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Ninja vs Wild Pigs TT1 1.9km', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 1916.4, 'average_grade': 0.1, 'maximum_grade': 12.1, 'elevation_high': 123.8, 'elevation_low': 114.2, 'start_latlng': [51.195783, 16.94136], 'end_latlng': [51.184102, 16.935455], 'start_latitude': 51.195783, 'start_longitude': 16.94136, 'end_latitude': 51.184102, 'end_longitude': 16.935455, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': None, 'state': None, 'country': None, 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661870069, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'las rędziński od Lesicy', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 154, 'moving_time': 154, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:52:54Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:52:54Z', 'distance': 992.9, 'start_index': 638, 'end_index': 663, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 76.9, 'average_heartrate': 121.7, 'max_heartrate': 143.0, 'segment': {'id': 13897839, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'las rędziński od Lesicy', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 1001.4, 'average_grade': 0.2, 'maximum_grade': 5.3, 'elevation_high': 116.0, 'elevation_low': 112.0, 'start_latlng': [51.18279, 16.935707], 'end_latlng': [51.174139, 16.935356], 'start_latitude': 51.18279, 'start_longitude': 16.935707, 'end_latitude': 51.174139, 'end_longitude': 16.935356, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Województwo dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': 3, 'achievements': [{'type_id': 3, 'type': 'pr', 'rank': 3}], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661870095, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'las rędziński ', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 311, 'moving_time': 311, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T08:55:54Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T10:55:54Z', 'distance': 2069.5, 'start_index': 668, 'end_index': 720, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 75.5, 'average_heartrate': 124.5, 'max_heartrate': 139.0, 'segment': {'id': 17205585, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'las rędziński ', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 2061.4, 'average_grade': -0.0, 'maximum_grade': 24.0, 'elevation_high': 154.8, 'elevation_low': 123.3, 'start_latlng': [51.173137, 16.936221], 'end_latlng': [51.160568, 16.951164], 'start_latitude': 51.173137, 'start_longitude': 16.936221, 'end_latitude': 51.160568, 'end_longitude': 16.951164, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Województwo dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661870120, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'most Milenijny - most Osobowicki', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 251, 'moving_time': 251, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T09:14:08Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T11:14:08Z', 'distance': 1839.9, 'start_index': 842, 'end_index': 887, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 107.9, 'average_heartrate': 121.1, 'max_heartrate': 135.0, 'segment': {'id': 1717029, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'most Milenijny - most Osobowicki', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 1893.8, 'average_grade': -0.1, 'maximum_grade': 3.0, 'elevation_high': 115.0, 'elevation_low': 108.4, 'start_latlng': [51.13581324, 17.00179225], 'end_latlng': [51.13302831, 17.02771734], 'start_latitude': 51.13581324, 'start_longitude': 17.00179225, 'end_latitude': 51.13302831, 'end_longitude': 17.02771734, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661870150, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Most Trzebnicki → North', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 38, 'moving_time': 38, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T09:23:19Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T11:23:19Z', 'distance': 232.7, 'start_index': 956, 'end_index': 967, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 117.9, 'average_heartrate': 132.7, 'max_heartrate': 138.0, 'segment': {'id': 9151698, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Most Trzebnicki → North', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 238.8, 'average_grade': -0.1, 'maximum_grade': 5.0, 'elevation_high': 112.8, 'elevation_low': 109.5, 'start_latlng': [51.131433, 17.037125], 'end_latlng': [51.133468, 17.036089], 'start_latitude': 51.131433, 'start_longitude': 17.037125, 'end_latitude': 51.133468, 'end_longitude': 17.036089, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Województwo dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661870210, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Wałem Karłowickim na zachód', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 190, 'moving_time': 190, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T09:24:00Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T11:24:00Z', 'distance': 1525.6, 'start_index': 969, 'end_index': 999, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 114.1, 'average_heartrate': 126.3, 'max_heartrate': 134.0, 'segment': {'id': 2316334, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Wałem Karłowickim na zachód', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 1525.96, 'average_grade': -0.1, 'maximum_grade': 3.6, 'elevation_high': 114.9, 'elevation_low': 109.0, 'start_latlng': [51.13355261273682, 17.036164300516248], 'end_latlng': [51.13255826756358, 17.05651237629354], 'start_latitude': 51.13355261273682, 'start_longitude': 17.036164300516248, 'end_latitude': 51.13255826756358, 'end_longitude': 17.05651237629354, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}, {'id': 48661870176, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Wał Karłowicki --> east', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 173, 'moving_time': 173, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T09:24:04Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T11:24:04Z', 'distance': 1403.0, 'start_index': 970, 'end_index': 997, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 115.9, 'average_heartrate': 126.0, 'max_heartrate': 132.0, 'segment': {'id': 15095539, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Wał Karłowicki --> east', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 1427.4, 'average_grade': -0.2, 'maximum_grade': 3.2, 'elevation_high': 114.0, 'elevation_low': 108.0, 'start_latlng': [51.133616, 17.036358], 'end_latlng': [51.133125, 17.055611], 'start_latitude': 51.133616, 'start_longitude': 17.036358, 'end_latitude': 51.133125, 'end_longitude': 17.055611, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'Województwo dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': True}, {'id': 48661870226, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Sępolno - wzdłuż kanału powodziowego', 'activity': {'id': 1929653585, 'resource_state': 1}, 'athlete': {'id': 3255732, 'resource_state': 1}, 'elapsed_time': 301, 'moving_time': 301, 'start_date': '2018-10-27T09:32:55Z', 'start_date_local': '2018-10-27T11:32:55Z', 'distance': 2101.5, 'start_index': 1080, 'end_index': 1118, 'device_watts': False, 'average_watts': 83.5, 'average_heartrate': 135.6, 'max_heartrate': 144.0, 'segment': {'id': 2358422, 'resource_state': 2, 'name': 'Sępolno - wzdłuż kanału powodziowego', 'activity_type': 'Ride', 'distance': 2098.41, 'average_grade': 0.1, 'maximum_grade': 4.1, 'elevation_high': 123.9, 'elevation_low': 115.0, 'start_latlng': [51.12652288, 17.08336807], 'end_latlng': [51.11512742, 17.10493333], 'start_latitude': 51.12652288, 'start_longitude': 17.08336807, 'end_latitude': 51.11512742, 'end_longitude': 17.10493333, 'climb_category': 0, 'city': 'Wrocław', 'state': 'dolnośląskie', 'country': 'Poland', 'private': False, 'hazardous': False, 'starred': False}, 'kom_rank': None, 'pr_rank': None, 'achievements': [], 'hidden': False}]
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample input dataframe? It's not clear what `seff` looks like.

Comment: use `np.select(conditions, choices, default)`

Comment: @Chris, could you please post a complete example? I am not sure how to apply this to this specific case.

Comment: @barciewicz Sure, can you please provide a sample dataframe and expected output